# Bootstrap 3 grid issues Firefox mis-alignment

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having a problem with a bootstrap based layout in Firefox.

Whats happening is that the rows are transitioning to the right when there is more than one row, but in Chrome and IE11 it doesn't do this.

Screenshot of how it looks in Firefox > http://i.imgur.com/GJEClw9.png

Screenshot of how it looks in Chrome/IE11 > http://i.imgur.com/baxNdJa.png

This is my CSS/HTML

```css
.forumNavigation a:link, a:visited, a:hover, a:active {
 color: #000;
 text-decoration: none;
}
/*
 Category headers
*/
.catHeader {
 background-image: url(../../assets/img/bg.png);
 background-repeat: repeat;
 font-size: 14px;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #fff;
 line-height: 40px;
 padding-left: 30px;
}
.catHeader a {
 color: #fff;
 text-decoration: none;
}
/*
 Forum table borders to save space
*/
.forumTitleBlock, 
.forumReplyBlock, 
.forumlastPostInfo {
 border-right: 1px solid #ccc; 
 border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    vertical-align: middle;
 padding-top:8px;
 padding-bottom:8px;
}
.postIcon, 
.forumsLeftBlock, 
.forumStats {
 border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
 border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; 
 vertical-align: middle; 
}
/* 
 Columns of same height styles (Part of the above Forum styles)
*/
.row-same-height {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.col-md-height {
    display: table-cell;
    float: none !important;
}
/*
 Padding below each category
*/
.blank {
 padding:10px;
}
/*
 Forum Statistics Section
*/
.forumStats { 
 padding-top:7px;
 padding-bottom:5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-6 animated" data-animation="fadeInUp" data-animation-delay="900"></div>
 <div class="col-md-12 form-element animated" data-animation="fadeInUp" data-animation-delay="1200">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12 forumContainer">
   <div class="col-md-6 forumNavigation">Forum</div>
   <div class="col-md-6 forumMessages text-right">Messages</div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row"> 
   <div class="col-md-12 catHeader" id="catHeader"><a href="#">Categories</a><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="catHeader" href="#coll-1" style="float:right"><i class="fa fa-sort" style="color:#777;"></i></a></div>
   <div class="collapse in" id="coll-1">
    <div class="row-same-height">
     <div class="col-md-1 col-md-height forumsLeftBlock">icon</div>
     <div class="col-md-7 col-md-height forumTitleBlock">Forum Title<br />&nbsp;&nbsp;<small>test subtitle</small></div>
     <div class="col-md-1 col-md-height forumReplyBlock">Topics<br />Replies</div>
     <div class="col-md-3 col-md-height forumlastPostInfo">Last Post info</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-same-height">
     <div class="col-md-1 col-md-height forumsLeftBlock">icon</div>
     <div class="col-md-7 col-md-height forumTitleBlock">Forum Title<br />&nbsp;&nbsp;<small>test subtitle</small></div>
     <div class="col-md-1 col-md-height forumReplyBlock">Topics<br />Replies</div>
     <div class="col-md-3 col-md-height forumlastPostInfo">Last Post info</div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="blank"></div>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12 catHeader text-center" id="statsHeader">Forum Statistics<a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="statsHeader" href="#stats" style="float:right"><i class="fa fa-sort" style="color:#777;"></i></a></div>
   <div class="collapse in" id="stats">
    <div class="col-md-12 forumStats text-center">Topics: | Posts: | Members: </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: wow...that mess, can i provide for you an alternate way of do same thing?

Comment: How is it a mess when its a nested grid? http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting
And I do not want to use tables, the whole site is built around a bootstrap responsive theme.

Comment: @sford999 I cannot tell if that will fix your problem but in every case you are using the grid system wrong. Twitters grid system expects 12 columns per row (including offsets). In your first row you try to use 18 if your intents are set correctly (`col-md-6` plus `col-md-12`). In your first nested row you are trying to use 24 (`col-md-12` plus `col-md-6` plus `col-md-6`). And so on... Start by fixing those errors and you have a good chance that your code generates the output you want in every browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After what Jey wrote, I rewrote the code to the following

```html
<div class="row forumContainer">
 <div class="col-md-8 forumNavigation">Forum</div>
 <div class="col-md-4 forumMessages text-right">Messages</div>
</div>
<div class="row">   
 <div class="col-md-12 catHeader" id="catHeader"><a href="#">Categories</a>
 <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="catHeader" href="#coll-1" style="float:right"><i class="fa fa-sort" style="color:#777;"></i></a>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="collapse in" id="coll-1">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="row-same-height">
   <div class="col-md-1 col-md-height forumsLeftBlock">icon</div>
   <div class="col-md-7 col-md-height forumTitleBlock">Forum Title<br />&nbsp;&nbsp;<small>test subtitle<?php echo $forum['subtitle']; ?></small></div>
   <div class="col-md-1 col-md-height forumReplyBlock">Topics<br />Replies</div>
   <div class="col-md-3 col-md-height forumlastPostInfo">Last Post info</div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="row-same-height">
   <div class="col-md-1 col-md-height forumsLeftBlock">icon</div>
   <div class="col-md-7 col-md-height forumTitleBlock">Forum Title<br />&nbsp;&nbsp;<small>test subtitle<?php echo $forum['subtitle']; ?></small></div>
   <div class="col-md-1 col-md-height forumReplyBlock">Topics<br />Replies</div>
   <div class="col-md-3 col-md-height forumlastPostInfo">Last Post info</div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="blank"></div>
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-12 catHeader text-center" id="statsHeader">Forum Statistics<a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="statsHeader" href="#stats" style="float:right"><i class="fa fa-sort" style="color:#777;"></i></a></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
 <div class="collapse in" id="stats">
  <div class="col-md-12 forumStats text-center">Topics: 1234 | Posts: 5678 | Members: 1234</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That code looks better. Does your problem persist? Two things that still come to my mind: Once you are using `row`s you should always use them as "outer containers" so your `<div class="collapse in" id="coll-1"><!-- [...] --></div>` should be surrounded by `<div class="row"><div class="col-md-12"></div></div>` as well to prevent unexpected paddings/margins. From your code we also don't see if you have a surrounding `container` or `container-fluid`. While some things may work without one you always should use one to house your grid system (http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-container).

Comment: The container is located in the _header.inc.php which is included before the code above

Comment: No its fixed now, thanks for pointing out the errors of my code, it made me realize what I'd done wrong.
I've already added the collapse div in a row now so thanks for that :)